# How can I iterate through cells on the 1st column and update the 2nd column?

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        //do operations with cell
    }
}
```

I have a host name in the 1st cell and an image in the second cell.

I want to ping the first cell and if I get a reply then I want to update the 2nd column with one of these 2 images

```
Properties.Resources.online
```

or

```
Properties.Resources.offline
```

---

Update

Column 1 contains a Server Name
Column 2 is an image from Resources (to show a GREEN or RED). That represents if the computer is online or offline

Column 3 contains the process name (like explorer.exe) that we are interested in making sure is online

Column 4 is just like #2 except it's purpose is to tell us if the process is running or not

I have the code to check the process in column 3

I also have done the part that checks if the server is online

I've tested it with Console.WriteLine that initattes from a button

Comment: you can do this using a for loop or foreach I will post a simple example

Comment: do you have a method already in regards to how you would `ping` can you please show more code if you have it otherwise I think that others will find this a bit unclear as to what you are trying to say

Comment: please update your question and show an example of what the data looks like in the first cell in your DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work if I understand everything correctly.  Some of this is a bit of pseudo-code but I think it should make sense.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
{
    if (ping(row.Cells[0]))
    {
        row.Cells[1].Value = Properties.Resources.online;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Cells[1].Value = Properties.Resources.offline;
    }

    if (checkProcess(row.Cells[2]))
    {
        row.Cells[3].Value = Properties.Resources.online;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Cells[3].Value = Properties.Resources.offline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what I needed help with is updating the cells

Comment: I don't think you need a nested loop you can do this with a single foreach loop or a single for loop I will post an example `row.Cells[i + 1]` wont work because you need to focus only on cells 1 and 2 which equate to `cell[0] and cell[1]`

Comment: @MethodMan good call.  I think I was thinking there could be more than two cells per row

Comment: He clearly states updating the second column but the OP will need to provide more information in regards to what `ping` means unless they are using a real call to Ping.. then both our answers may have to change can't determine it would be nice to see what the contents of the first column look like

Comment: Actually it's column 1 and 3. I'm updating column 2 and 4 based on the results of 1,3

Comment: @softwareisfun so you are pinging 1 and 3 and putting the results in 2 and 4?

Comment: and does that mean you are checking `row.Cells[1]` or are you checking the `first` cell which would be `row.Cells[0]`

Comment: While I am pinging column 1 and running a WMI Query on column 3 to see if a process is running

Comment: so ping column 1, run a query on column 3, and add either online or offline to 2 and 4?

Comment: @softwareisfun can you please update the question with these requirements

Comment: Thanks @TimFreese I have a question. Is there any reason not to use a switch statement on the cells.ColumnIndex?

Comment: @softwareisfun I think a switch statement would also work.

Comment: Thank you. cells[i] . is the 1st column 0 and 2nd column 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.Rows)
{
    if(ping(row.Cells[1]))
    {
        row.Cells[2].Value = Properties.Resources.online;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Cells[2].Value = Properties.Resources.offline;
    }
}
```

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. At the very least you should point out the specific issue, what was done to resolve it, and why.

Comment: @IInspectable what are you talking about it's pretty straight forward if this is a comment geared towards the OP then delete the comment and post under their original question

Comment: This answer was flagged as a low-quality post. While reviewing I found this to be true, and I pointed out specific points that could be improved. If it's obvious to you, write about it. It may not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: I am still waiting on the OP to provide more information in regards to what was asked in many of the previous comments also the OP needs to provide more info vs changing what they want in comments vs updating the original question..

Comment: In that case, heed the advice under [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem. [...]"*